# what are updateOne() mandatory fields

Tags: database, mongodb

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ],
     hint:  <document|string>        // Available starting in MongoDB 4.2.1
   }
)
```

I can understand the `update` argument is mandatory, or how will you update a document, but is the `filter` argument also mandatory?
I took that code from [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/), does the `<>` mean that they are mandatory?

Comment: Well if you *didn't* pass a filter argument, then the update argument would get passed to the filter parameter anyway (and options would get passed as the update). By the same token as *"how will you update a document"* explaining why the update is required, *"how will you know which document to update"* explains why filter is. They're also not listed as optional in the table.

Comment: [updateOne parameters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#parameters) specifies if any of the parameters are optional. The `filter` and `update` parameters are mandatory; and in case you don't have a filter criteria, you can pass an empty document for the filter: `{ }`. The `< >` doesn't mean mandatory; it means a value is to be substituted by you, when you build the query.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks a lot , now i understand that both arguments are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @prasad_ updateOne parameters specifies if any of the parameters are optional. The filter and update parameters are mandatory; and in case you don't have a filter criteria, you can pass an empty document for the filter: { }. The < > doesn't mean mandatory; it means a value is to be substituted by you, when you build the query